# Tabela já existe ao criar uma nova tabela mysql, mesmo ela não existindo

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Tenho uma base de dados do qual exclui acidentalmente uma tabela e quando tento recriá-la, diz que a tabela  já existe, porém ela não aparece. Ao executar o comando:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

Ela não aparece! Como posso corrigir isso?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver. Ao criar a tabela, alterei `ENGINE=InnoDB` para `ENGINE=MyISAM`.